# Firestore Rules: resource.data.keys() doesn't contain all fields in read

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

### The Setup

---

I have a collection in Firebase Firestore that has the following fields:

```js
(["active" , "created" , "description" , "displayName" , "expires" , "image" , "type" , "uid" , "userName"])
```

where `"expires"` is optional.

The write rules ensure that every object follows that form and are tested successfully.

### The Problem

---

When trying to read from the collection, I have a rule that states the following:

```js
let seeUnexpired = !("expires" in resource.data.keys()) ||
resource.data.expires > request.time ||
request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
```

That prohibits users other than the author from reading expired entries. This rule was not prohibiting reads, however. I am testing using a local emulator with carefully curated data and am confident that the expire field exists and is outdated for this test.

### Details

---

In attempt to debug I discovered that the condition causing the rule to fail was `!("expires" in resource.data.keys())`.

Running the tests with `debug(resource.data.keys())` printed out this object to `firestore-debug.log`:

```js
list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "active"
  }
}
```

where `"active"` only shows up when using this query condition in the request: `...collection('collection_name').where('active', '==', true).get()`.

This indicates to me that `resource.data.keys()` only includes the fields from the resource that are referenced in `where` clauses on the read request. That means a request can circumvent a "field must not exist" rule by simply not including it in a query.

Debug:

```
Mar 31, 2021 12:34:48 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
list_value {
  values {
    string_value: "active"
  }
}
```

### Tests

---

Test:

```js
await firestoreAdmin.collection(COLLECTIONS.items).doc(mockItem.id).update({active: true, expires: new Date('01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT')});
const query = firestore.collection(COLLECTIONS.items).where('active', '==', true); //unAuthed firestore instance
await assertFails(query.get());
```

Rule:

```js
function readItemRules() {
  let seeActive = resource.data.active == true || request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
  let seeUnexpired = !("expires" in resource.data.keys()) ||
  resource.data.expires > request.time ||
  request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid; TODO figure out expiration rules
  return seeActive && seeUnexpired;
}
```

Data:
[image: Firestore Emulator Data]

### The Question

---

Is my understanding of this problem accurate, or am I missing a detail or syntax quirk? Is this behavior intentional, and if so how should I modify my rules/data to enforce this kind of security?

Comment: A naive solution I identify is to have an additional boolean field like "hasExpiration" that is required and can be queried to see if there is no expiration before checking if the date is past. I feel like this adds data parity complexity. Write rules could be used to ensure parity between hasExpiration and the existence of an expiration field, but that seems much more error prone than just checking for the field.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you tested the problem? Mostly, I'm looking for the code that you ran, ideally logging its results, and then a screenshot of a document that is included in the results that you'd expect to not be there.

Comment: Screenshots and testing data included.

Comment: I hope you know that [rules don't filter data on their own](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), so this code `firestore.collection(COLLECTIONS.items).where('active', '==', true)` can't be enough. I'm not sure why the read is allowed, but most likely one of the other conditions is met. Can you log the UID of the current user just before the query? Also: where are you executing this JavaScript code?

Comment: The firestore instance has no user so uid is empty. I am pretty certain the reason the query succeeds is because the read operation only loads the fields specifically stated in the query. This works if your rule says "field" must be "value" or "field" must exist because if it doesn't come with the query that will fail. It doesn't work when checking "field" must *not* exist because when you do not include it in the query *it does not exist as far as firestore is concerned*. As long as the client omits that field from the query filter, it'll always pass the doesn't exist check.

Comment: The code is running in from jest in a node environment against a firestore emulator. Firebase is being emulated with @firebase/rules-testing-library. It seems I am most explicitly looking for a rule which allows expire to not exist or be in the future, but prohibits a query where expire isn't a filtered field...

Comment: It sounds like you're using the Admin SDK for Node.js in that case. The Admin SDKs run with elevated administrative privileges and bypass all security rules. **Edit**: I just noticed the `firestoreAdmin` in your code, which confirms that you're using an Admin SDK.

Answer (score 3):

My discovery was that for a read rule, firestore only seems to load the fields from the document which are mentioned in the query. This makes a lot of sense for rules that require the field to exist or match something, because if you don't include it in a query they're guaranteed to fail (as they will be tested against something undefined). It just doesn't work here because if you omit it from the query it'll pass the does not exist rule no matter what since firestore omits that field from the whole resource when doing the check.

My solution was simply to add another, boolean field "hasExpiration" that indicates whether or not the "expires" field will be present. I am a little unsatisfied with this solution because it adds complexity and falls on the client/write rules to ensure that there is parity between those fields.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations

Comment: I find it absolutely incredible that this isn't well documented. It's dangerously unexpected behavior that directly contradicts the Firebase docs. The Firebase docs say "The resource variable refers to the requested document, and resource.data is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the resource variable, see the reference documentation." The linked documentation says resource is "The firestore document being read or written." and data is "Map of the document data.". No mention of this case in which that is not true!

Comment: @imagio EXACTLY.  What the actual is Google doing

Answer (score 2):

https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/01/code-review-security-rules

The examples they have on this page are great.  Especially the final one:

```
allow update: if
  // Immutable fields are unchanged
  request.resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).unchangedKeys().hasAll([
    "authorUID",
    "publishedAt",
    "url"
  ]) &&
  // Required fields are present
  request.resource.data.keys().hasAll([
    "content",
    "title",
    "visible"
  ]);
```

It shows the list of `keys()` and a way to calculate `unchangedKeys()` in a smart way.