# Firebase Security Rules for allow read treats request.resource.data differently than resource.data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner;
    }
  }
}
```

The above is my working version, but if I switch the `allow read` line to:

`allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner;`

Then I get "Missing or insufficient permissions." an error when fetching documents.

New to Firestore and I didn't see anything in the documents to suggest this should happen.

Shouldn't `resource` and `request.resource` be the same for `read` requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't resource and request.resource be the same for **read** requests?

No, they aren't the same: As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request), `request` is the incoming request context and the `request.resource` value is present **on write requests only**.

For a **read** rule, "the `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document" (excerpt from the [part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) of the doc about data validation).

Comment: can you please fix your answer and ask the Firebase team to fix their product or docs?  It's not a comprehensive map, it's a mini map based on the query parameters only:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059684/9938721